# Is it possible to nth child a table cell if it contains a number greater than "x"?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I currently have a table with some dynamically generated data and I would like to highlight a table row if a cell contained a number that was greater then, lets say "50".

Is this something that can be done just with CSS? or would JQuery need to be involved?

At the moment I am just using this CSS to help separate each row visually.

```
.data tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpXae/)

Comment: Forget JavaScript, this is a problem better solved by adjusting the code that generates your data in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in pure **`CSS`**.  Using CSS, you can't get the innerHTML.

You have to use **`javascript`** or **`jQuery`.**

A simple looping is needed

```
$('td').each(function () {  //loop through each tds
    if (+$(this).text() > 50) { // + is used to parse it to integer type
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpXae/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a form of conditional formatting, right? If so it seems like your only option is Javascript and from googling around there are quite a few options. Here's the top google link: https://gist.github.com/rdrgrtz/1082791